# Accessing interface/object(s) from a module loaded in a different process

Tags: delphi, dll

I'm working on a dll that is loaded in application A, I want to share interface/object(s) between application A and another application B, so, here's the idea:

[foreign application A] <- [my dll] <-> [my application B]

Ideally would be to "somehow" reroute functions in the dll to [my application B]

I'm interested in an elegant solution, one that wouldn't require too much compromise, thoughts?

**EDIT**:
[application A] is written in C, [my dll] and [application B] are written in the same delphi version.

Comment: If both A and B are applications written in (the same version of) Delphi you could simply use runtime packages.

Comment: @TOndrej sorry, I wasn't very clear, only the dll and app B are written in the same Delphi version, app A is written in C

Comment: In that case probably COM is the easiest.

Comment: Ya, you need out-of-proc COM server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you expose an automation interface in [My Application B] which [My DLL] can access and forward function calls on to?

```
[My Application B]

IMyRemoteInterface = interface(IDispatch)
    ... Ole interface functions here ...
end;

TMyRemoteInterfaceImpl = class(TAutoObject, IMyRemoteInterface)
    ... Implementation gubbins ...
end;
```

and then

```
[My Application C]

Server = CreateOleObject(MyApplicationB.MyRemoteInterface)
....
Server.DoStuff
```

Obviously there's more to it than that, but you get the gist.

Comment: +1 thank you, wasn't thinking about COM... I'll give this question a bit more time and then, if no one comes up with other idea, I'll accept yours.

Comment: accepted your answer, it seems that this is the best solution thus far, thank you!